# How do you filter out successful connections in HAProxy logs?

Tags: node.js, openshift, haproxy

I am running a Nodejs app on openshift. HAProxy is enabled. I see a lot of extra http logs. Its a continuous stream of logs. Example -

```
127.13.141.129 - - [Fri, 01 Nov 2013 18:08:45 GMT] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 6481 "-" "-"
```

I don't want these logs to contaminate my log file. How can I get rid of these lines?

Answer (score 1):

HAProxy polls your applications to make sure that each node is up and running, or it gets taken out of the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. **`option log-separate-errors`** - This will log the errors onto a separate file. (recommended) You may still need the HTTP200s for verification purposes. I suggest you keep the "main" log file intact.
2. **`option dontlog-normal`** - This will ignore successful connections.

**Source:** [HAProxy Manual](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt)